# Is it possible to have multiple dynamic method names in a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading through the ES6 class information on [Babel.js's documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#classes) and noticed that it says that objects can now have dynamic property names:

```
var obj = {
    ...

    // Computed (dynamic) property names
    [ "prop_" + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

This seems like it would be useful in classes as well. Is it possible to do something similar in an ES6 class without doing it in a constructor, i.e.:

```
class Foo {
  [ "read" + (...)(['format1', 'format2']) ] {
    // my format reading function
  }
}
```

rather than doing something like this in the constructor:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(opts) {
    let formats = ['format1', 'format2'];
    let self = this;

    formats.forEach(function(format) {
      self["read" + format] = function() {
        // my format reading function
      }
    })
  }
}
```

In other words, I want to be able to take some array, such as `['format1', 'format2']` and create two methods, `readformat1` and `readformat2`, in the class dynamically, without using the constructor. Is this possible?

Comment: "but hopefully it's understandable" --- it's not :-S

Comment: ahh i changed it to use the `function` syntax rather than the `=>` syntax, so it should make more sense now.

Comment: Just add them dynamically to the prototype as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you only missed the required `()` for the method signature:

```
class Foo {
  [ "read" + ((format) => format)(myFormat) ]() {
    // my format reading function          // ^--- this what missed
  }
}
```

Babel repl: [long and ugly url here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&playground=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20myFormat%20%3D%20'foo'%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5B%20%22read%22%20%2B%20((format)%20%3D%3E%20format)(myFormat)%20%5D()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20123%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20)

As of your updated question: it's not possible (at least I'm not aware of it). So you can create methods with names resolved in runtime, but you cannot create N methods from the array using that syntax.

Comment: great, thanks! it kind of sucks that the `()` are required but it looks cleaner than the `constructor` way that would otherwise be used, i think.

Comment: actually, i realized after i accepted it that this didn't quite answer my question. what i meant was i wanted to dynamically assign method names similar to the way the constructor at the end of the question works, in the shorthand way similar to what you answered as. please see my updated question

Comment: @zerkms [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects would make this possible. They need browser support though as there is no way to polyfill this feature.

Comment: @zerkms you just saved my life lol. Thanks. 
Spent almost half an hour searching.

Answer (score 5):

I found this question in a first Google link, so should give another helpful answer :)

ES6 classes is mostly just a syntactic sugar, so you still can use prototypes and do something like

```
class Foo { ... }

let formats = [ 'format1', 'format2' ];
formats.forEach(function(format) {
    Foo.prototype['read' + format] = function () { ... }
});
```

I've not found a better way.